# Indy 10 and Xmailer : "Could Not Load SSL Library" or "SSL Error"

Tags: ubuntu, email, openssl, freepascal, indy10

I am writing a program on Ubuntu that will send email on the Internet.

I am testing 2 tools/components to see which one works, but every time I try to send an email from my program, I get an error as follows.

**For Indy 10:**

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
   SMTP.Host := 'smtp.gmail.com';  //  smtp.gmail.com is here
   SMTP.Port := 465;
   SMTP.AuthType:=satDefault;

   SMTP.UserName:='myemailaddress';
   SMTP.Password:='**** **** **** ****'; //<<<<< App Password

   //setup mail message
   MailMessage.From.Address := 'myemailaddress@gmail.com';
   MailMessage.Recipients.EMailAddresses := 'myemailaddress@gmail.com';
   MailMessage.Subject := 'Amazon Order';
   MailMessage.Body.Text := 'Hey, Your Amazon order is delivered.';

   //send mail
   try
      try
         SMTP.Connect;
         SMTP.Send(MailMessage);
      except on E:Exception do
         showmessage('ERROR: ' + E.Message);
      end;
      finally
         if SMTP.Connected then SMTP.Disconnect;
      end;
end;
```

When I execute the above code, I get the following error:

> ERROR: Could not load SSL Library

[image]

**For XMailer:**

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
   IdOpenSSLSetLibPath('/home/bobby/testingemail/');
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
   Mail: TSendMail;
begin
   Mail := TSendMail.Create;
   try
      // Mail
      Mail.Sender := 'myemailaddress <myemailaddress@gmail.com>';
      Mail.Receivers.Add('myemailaddress@gmail.com');
      Mail.Subject := 'Amazon order';
      Mail.Message.Add('Hey, Your Amazon order is delivered.');

      // SMTP
      Mail.Smtp.UserName := 'myemailaddress';
      Mail.Smtp.Password := '**** **** **** ****';  //<<<< App Password
      Mail.Smtp.Host := 'smtp.gmail.com';
      Mail.Smtp.Port := '587';
      mail.Smtp.FullSSL:=false;
      Mail.Smtp.TLS := True;

      Mail.Send;
      ShowMessage('SUCCESS :) ');
   finally
      Mail.Free;
 end;
end;
```

When I execute the above code for XMailer, I get the following error:

> SSL Error:TSendmail.

[image]

So, I found an info on this error on a website and followed their instructions.

1. Downloaded openssl-1.0.2u, extracted tar file, ran `./config` and `make` terminal commands.
2. Then, copied and pasted the following files into my project folder (`libcrypto.so` and `libssl.so`).

   [image]

After that, I rebooted my computer and tested my program, but I still get the same error `Can't load SSL Library`.

Any idea?

Comment: When the error happens in the Indy code, what does Indy's `WhichFailedToLoad()` function report?  Is it having trouble loading the `.so` files themselves, or finding exported functions in the `.so` files? There is a difference. Also, why are you using `IdOpenSSLSetLibPath()` with `TSendMail`? `IdOpenSSLSetLibPath()` is an Indy function, but `TSendMail` doesn't use Indy (it uses Synapse instead). That function call should be in your Indy example instead.

Comment: In any case, do note that on modern systems, the *unversioned* `.so` files are typically just symlinks to whatever OpenSSL library is installed on the system, and that is usually an updated version that is not compatible with Indy's default `SSLIOHandler`. So, when using Indy, try placing *versioned* `.so` files in your app folder and then call `IdOpenSSLSetLibPath(...)` AND `IdOpenSSLSetCanLoadSymLinks(False)` at runtime to ensure the files in your app folder are used.

Comment: BTW, the XMailer error message *should be*: `TSendMail: SSL error: Could not found the SSL library.` according to the source code in [this repo](https://github.com/MFernstrom/xmailer)

Comment: Hi Remy... `WhichFailedToLoad()` returned `Failed = "Failed to load /home/bobby/testingemail/libcrypto.so."` but I do have a copy of that file in my program folder.

Comment: Do you also have `libssl.so` in tbe same folder? Are they the same version? Are they actual libraries, or just symlinks to other libraries? It makes a big difference. Where did you get the `.so` files from? Need more details about your setup.

Comment: I downloaded openssl from openssl website. I also have libssl.so in the same folder.

Comment: The error message means `libcrypto.so` could not be loaded into memory, before Indy then looks for expected functions in it. That could be an issue with the path, or permissions, or dependencies. You will have to check all of those.

Comment: Also note that you have unversioned `.so` files, and by default Indy will try to load them before versioned files, unless you call `IdOpenSSLSetCanLoadSymLinks(False)` or `IdOpenSSLSetLoadSymLinksFirst(False)`. Since you got the files from OpenSSL's site, I'm betting they are a newer version than Indy currently supports. Indy's default `SSLIOHandler` supports only up to OpenSSL 1.0.2u. [This WIP `SSLIOHandler`](https://github.com/indySockets/indy/pull/299) supports OpenSSL 1.1x/3.0.

Comment: @RemyLebeau OH MY GOD!!! Your last comment really made me think. After reading your comment, I searched the openssl folder for `.so` file with version number after it like `libssl.1.0.0`. Once I found them, I copied them to my project folder. Viola!!! It WORKED for Indy10... Thanks.